# How do i insert object in parenting structure?

Tags: parent

I have object A and B. A is a child of B (B is the parent):

```
A --> B
```

Now i want to insert new object C into that structure , in the middle so between A and B :

```
A --> C --> B
```

B parent of C and C is parent of A.

Is there any single function for this ? so i don't need to do it twice (A to C then C to B) ?

second question, the opposite of above. How then i can remove C from structure without breaking ? If C has transformation then deleting C will cause A to jump. Any tip?

Comment: Make C a child of B (in other words parent C to B) using Ctrl+P, and then make A a child of C (or in other words parent A to C). For the second question look at the comments [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201767/removing-intermediate-object-from-parenting-tree).

Comment: in my case , the child (A) is a group of multiple object , so to say B is parent of 30 object directly, where this 30 obj has its own children and grand children etc. Rather than select that 30 object and its hierarchy and parenting them to C (some of the item in hierarchy is hidden - so select children or select hierarchy from outliner will skip them) , then C to B(top most parent), i prefer  a new workflow to select just B(parent) then be able to insert C down directly in the middle of structure between B and A.

Comment: Ah, you did not specify that in your question. Yes, that would make it a problem to easily insert an object in the hierarchy. Perhaps you could emphasize in your question if and how it can be done via Python script, (I assme you were, but it wasn't clear to me at first).